# Prove that a sequence that contains subsequences that converges to every unit fraction contains a subsequence that converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

How can I proceed with this proof?

Prove that a sequence that contains subsequences that converges to every point in the set $\{1/n: n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ contains a subsequence that converges to $0$.

Suppose that such a sequence, $a_n$, existed. Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$. By the Archimedean Property we can find a large enough $m$ such that we have a subsequence converging to $1/m$.

Is it correct to say that: So, since $1/m$ tends to zero, we have a subsequence that tends to zero?
I think something is missing.

Comment: This is awfully confusing. A sequence can't converge to more than at most one thing. In your proof, you say suppose such a sequence exists. But that's what you're trying to prove.

Comment: I meant to write "that contains subsequences … " I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following sequence [OEIS A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260)

$$1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$$

and then its reciprocal

$$\frac11,\frac11,\frac12,\frac11,\frac12,\frac13,\frac11,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac11,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\ldots$$

which has subsequences converging to every unit fraction while the whole sequence does not converge to $0$ as it does not converge at all.

It does have a subsequence which converges to $0$. Was that what you had intended to ask?

To find such a subsequence, look for a sequence of ${N_1},{N_2},{N_3},\ldots$ where $N_m>N_{m-1}$ and $0 < a_{N_m} < \frac2m$.  Given $N_{m-1}$, such an $N_m$ must exist as you have a subsequence converging to $\frac1m$ and so an infinite number of terms strictly between $\frac1m-\frac1m$ and $\frac1m + \frac1m$.  Then $a_{N_1},a_{N_2},a_{N_3},\ldots$  converges to $0$ so is an example of the desired subsequence.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I fixed my question now. How can I prove that it contains a subsequence that tends to zero?

Comment: I added one approach

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't $\frac {1}{m}$ have been used instead? We have an infinite number of terms strictly between $0$ and $\frac {1}{m}$, namely the ones that converge to $\frac {1}{m+1}$.

Comment: @thegoodhunter-9115 My addition was one of many possible approaches.  Yours works too, though lacks my symmetry around $\frac1m$.  So use whichever you prefer

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it, because the statement is not true.  A sequence that contains subsequences converging to different limits does not converge.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write something else. I fixed my question now.