# fractional part of square root 2 to contain a subsequence that converges to 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

the question is

> Consider the sequence $a_n = \{({{n*\sqrt{2}}})\}, n ≥ 1. $ where {} means the fractional part of $a$. Show that the sequence an contains a subsequence that converges to 0

here's my attempt. I think about using Continued fraction
since we know $$
\sqrt{2} = 1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \dots}},
$$

if I can pick certain numbers to prove the pattern to be monotonic with strictly decreasing, then it's done? but I am stuck here and don't know how to deal with it. Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks!

or maybe I can do the transform such that $f_0=0, f_1=\sqrt2-1= \frac{1}{\sqrt2+1}$, I found that $f_5 =5\sqrt2-7= \frac{1}{\sqrt5+7} $. (i use $f$ stands for fractional part) it may work if there's more pattern like this, but it's probably a dead end.

I don't know if this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549435/prove-that-a-sequence-that-contains-subsequences-that-converges-to-every-unit-fr) will help, but I can't really understand what's the first answer doing there.

i notice that using Bolzano–Weierstrass can prove it to be bounded but how to show it's necessarily leading to 0?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What has your second sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to do with the first one?

Comment: sorry for confusion, updated

Comment: Consider the fractional parts $n\sqrt2-\lfloor n\sqrt2\rfloor=n\sqrt2-m=n\left(\sqrt2-\frac mn\right)$ and check which rational approximations of an algebraic number can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

So , $$a_n=\{n\sqrt2\}=n\sqrt2-\lfloor n\sqrt2\rfloor$$

and we know $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ $$0\leq n\sqrt2-\lfloor n\sqrt2\rfloor<1\implies0\leq a_n<1$$

Hence the sequence is *bounded* .

Now according to [Bolzano Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) which states that Every bounded sequence has a *convergent subsequence* , proves that your sequence also has a convergent subsequence

Comment: The question asks for a subsequence converging to *zero.*